# Unable to marshall request to JSON: Java heap space

Tags: java, .net, jenkins, deployment, aws-lambda

I am trying to continuous deploy .net core app from jenkins to AWS Lambda but getting this error

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to marshall request to JSON: Java heap space
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.transform.UpdateFunctionCodeRequestMarshaller.marshall(UpdateFunctionCodeRequestMarshaller.java:99)
    at com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.updateFunctionCode(AWSLambdaClient.java:1821)
    at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.service.LambdaDeployService.updateCodeOnly(LambdaDeployService.java:247)
    at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.service.LambdaDeployService.deployLambda(LambdaDeployService.java:57)
    at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.upload.LambdaUploader.upload(LambdaUploader.java:51)
    at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.callable.DeployCallable.call(DeployCallable.java:46)
    at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.callable.DeployCallable.call(DeployCallable.java:23)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.upload.LambdaUploadBuildStep.perform(LambdaUploadBuildStep.java:81)
    at com.xti.jenkins.plugin.awslambda.upload.LambdaUploadBuildStep.perform(LambdaUploadBuildStep.java:69)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Build step 'AWS Lambda deployment' changed build result to FAILURE
Starting lambda invocation.
Lambda invoke request:
{FunctionName: gateway-api-cd-stack-AspNetCoreFunction-J3R1IEJBNZVG,InvocationType: Event,Payload: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0],}
```

Payload:

```
Lambda invoke response:
{StatusCode: 202,Payload: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0]}
```